# How to include canvas into a layout

Tags: android, android-layout, canvas

I have designed a canvas , now i want to include it into the xml file , how can i do this ?

My MainActivity file is as below:

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  CircularSeekBar circularSeekbar;
  private AudioManager audioManager = null; 
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      supe`enter code here`r.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      TextView tx =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytext);
      circularSeekbar =(CircularSeekBar) findViewById(R.id.mycanvas);
      audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
      circularSeekbar = new CircularSeekBar(this);
    -------------------
 }
```

my xml file looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:id="@+id/rel">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/mytext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Value"
    />

<com.example.semicirseek.MyCanvas
    android:id="@+id/mycanvas"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
    android:max="255"
    android:progress="0" />  

</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is the canvas comes on the screen when i run the app

Comment: what xml should come up first ?

Comment: I want the canvas to be within the xml

Comment: bt i presume it is inside the relative layout isnt it ?

Comment: yes , but when i run my app , oly the canvas comes up , the textView dosent

Comment: oh ok.. add layout_below="the textviews id" and then you will see it, and the line to the canvas block

Comment: post the code of your custom view.

Comment: @Dhara Shah even that dosent work

Comment: try try and u will succeed

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:id="@+id/rel">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/mytext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Value"
    />

<com.example.semicirseek.MyCanvas
    android:id="@+id/mycanvas"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
    android:max="255"
    android:progress="0" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/mytext"/>  

</RelativeLayout>
```